# Forward look up table(LUT) and reverse LUT, what is it? and why it is used?

Tags: image-processing, view, widget, screen

I am looking at some view(screen) building codes to draw GUIs, like transforming distorted lens view to a planar view. In that I came across the terms forward LUT and reverse LUT and I don't understand what is it and why it is being used?
Can someone please explain me or give some pointers where I can learn about them?

Answer (score 0):

A *"Look Up Table"*, or LUT is a small table, normally with 256 entries in it. It is used for applying *"point processes"* to images, i.e. where the new value after processing of each pixel only depends on the previous value at that point (and not any neighbouring pixels).

Instead of doing a load of maths or `if` statements for each of the 12 million pixels in your image, you just use the current 8-bit value of each pixel as an index into the Look Up Table to find the new value for that pixel. It is normally much faster than stalling your CPU doing `if` statements as it is just an indexing operation into a table. It is also very simple to implement in hardware at high speed.

You can use it to threshold an image, or to alter the contrast in an image, or to save space. In this last technique, you are basically creating an image with a palette of 256 colours, then instead of storing 3 bytes for each pixel (i.e. R, G and B), you just store 1 byte and use that byte to *"look up"* the colour - and as if by magic, your image is 1/3rd the size.

Here is a little example, I make a LUT with all elements below 64 black and all elements above that into white, then apply it to a greyscale image. I added the red border afterwards so you can see the extent of the image on Stack Overflow's white background:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open the input image as numpy array, convert to greyscale
npImage=np.array(Image.open("grey.png").convert("L"))

# Make a LUT (Look-Up Table) to translate image values
LUT=np.zeros(256,dtype=np.uint8)
for idx in range(64,255):
    # All pixels > 64 become white
    LUT[idx]=255

# Apply LUT
npImage = LUT[npImage]

# Apply LUT and save resulting image
Image.fromarray(npImage).save('result.png')
```

Start Image:

[image]

Result Image:

[image]

---

Here's another example where I make the LUT run backwards, so it inverts the image.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open the input image as numpy array, convert to greyscale
npImage=np.array(Image.open("grey.png").convert("L"))

# Make a LUT (Look-Up Table) to translate image values to their inverse/negative
# i.e. 0 input maps to 255 output
#      1 input maps to 254 output
LUT = np.arange(255,-1,-1,dtype=np.uint8)

# Apply LUT
npImage = LUT[npImage]

# Apply LUT and save resulting image
Image.fromarray(npImage).save('result.png')
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, Numpy, image, image processing, LUT, Look-Up Table, Lookup, negate, inverse, threshold